# Сверстать адаптивный дизайн - макет 1920х1080

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Мне дали макет в формате .psd размером в пикселях 1920Х1080. Как (какие техники) нужно использовать чтобы сверстать адаптивный дизайн с такого макета? Макетов для меньших разрешений не будет. Я сверстал для 1920Х1080 попиксельно и не понимаю немного куда двигаться дальше.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. См. [«Как задать хороший вопрос?»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) для прояснения ситуации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал так если макетов нет для менших разрешений, включял фантазию и двигал блоки как хотел, если они не помещались в данном разрешении экрана,  на свое усмотрение. Использовал @media (max-width: 1200px) {} Для нескольких экранов от большого до меньшего.